# Compiled Python script is unable to run commands given to it by user in Windows cmd

Tags: python, subprocess, pyinstaller

I have been working on this project recently but now I am facing some issues.

### The project

The project is an Intelligent Reverse shell client side program written in python that connects to our listener from the target machine trough `Websocket` and executes each command we send and returns the result of that command.

[Link to full source code](https://github.com/zNiGhTFuRyZNTT/Reverse_shell)

The code works perfectly when I compile it normally(not Single exe), but After I try to compile and run it as a single executable file, It runs and connects to our listener but it can not execute the commands I send to it.

Just this part of the code doesn't work after compiling to single exe:

```
            try:
                data = os.popen(cmd).read()
                if len(data) > 0:
                    ws.send(data)
                    ws.send(f"({os.getlogin()}windows)-[{os.getcwd()}]>")
                else:
                    ws.send(f"({os.getlogin()}windows)-[{os.getcwd()}]>")
            except Exception as e:
                ws.send(e)
                print(e)
```

Actually the only part that doesn't work is this part -> `data = os.popen(cmd).read()`
You can see the full source code [Here](https://github.com/zNiGhTFuRyZNTT/Reverse_shell) To better understand how does it work.

So The main question is:

#### Why does that line of code works and executes all commands when compiled normally and doesn't when it is compiled to a single file?

Comment: "Doesn't work" – surely you get an error?

Comment: Why do you 'compile' using `--noconsole` although it is a console application ?